# Como trabajar con fechas en varchar con formato 2211010 en oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

estoy intentando crear una consulta donde me traiga toda la información por ejemplo de todo el mes de diciembre del 2022 hasta el mes de marzo del 2023, pero el problema es que en la tabla donde quiero hacer la consulta el tipo de dato es en varchar2 y el formato del año está así: `2210906`

Empecé haciendo este query:

```
  select CTAFACTURA, SERIE, FOLIOFAC, UUID, TO_DATE(ffactura,'yyyMMdd'), 
  ffactura
  from REPDEF_NCR
  WHERE TO_DATE(ffactura,'yyyMMdd')> '01/12/22';
```

Pero me arrojó información de mas por ejemplo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se ve en la imagen en la columna fffactura `2210906` del año 2021, está arrojando información de mas, espero y me puedan ayudar por favor se los agradecería mucho con algunos ejemplo por favor, si hay algo que no se entienda con gusto lo pondré. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Un problema está en que el formato de fecha de la factura **no es estándar**, por lo que Oracle no lo va a poder convertir correctamente.
Por ejemplo, tomando el primer registro que aparece en la imagen:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('2210906', 'yyyMMdd'), 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS DDATE FROM DUAL;
```

```
DDATE
----------
2221-09-06
```

Es una fecha de **2 siglos** en el futuro, por lo que el `WHERE` se cumple y ves el resultado que tienes. Debió ser `0210906` para que corresponda a `2021-09-06`.

[Documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00210) de Oracle:

> `YYY`, `YY`, `Y` --> Last `3`, `2`, or `1` digit(s) of year.

Entonces `YYY` de `2021` es `021`, y de `2221` es `221`.

¿Has probado hacer la comparación cadena contra cadena?

```sql
...
WHERE ffactura >= '2221200' AND ffactura <= '2230331'
```

Comment: Hola @aeportugal, no lo había pensado en hacer la comparación entre cadenas, lo voy a intentar, solo hay algo que no entendí bien, aqui 2221200, por que se comenzó desde el 0? es por que empieza el recorrido?

Comment: Edité la pregunta agregando más información al respecto @cratus666jose .

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, creo que con esto si me va a ayudar bastante, lo que busco mas que nada es extraer esa información para utilizarla en otro proceso, de verdad te abradezco por la explicación, Saludos.